# Custom selected tab text style in SmartTabLayout

Tags: android

I'm using the SmartTabLayout from github https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

It works well, but what I want it is to put the selected title in bold

someone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SmartTabLayout mainTabs = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
final LinearLayout lyTabs = (LinearLayout) mainTabs.getChildAt(0);
changeTabsTitleTypeFace(lyTabs, 0);

  yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            changeTabsTitleTypeFace(lyTabs, position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });


public void changeTabsTitleTypeFace(LinearLayout ly, int position) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ly.getChildCount(); j++) {
        TextView tvTabTitle = (TextView) ly.getChildAt(j);
        tvTabTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL); 
        if (j == position) tvTabTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);       
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, tell me if works please.